# Do larger desktop photos use more resources?

Tags: macos, desktop

Does using a larger sized photo for one's desktop hinder performance? My new desktop photo is 3MBs, does it use more resources than say a 1MB sized photo?

Comment: What problem are you trying to measure? Are you looking for a tool that shows you how much effort or RAM is needed to set the picture? Its clear the GPU needs to draw each and every pixel on the screen no matter what you choose to display, so at worst, there's a resampling that happens once and the image gets cached.

Comment: No issue, just curiosity.  I try to keep my machine running as it's best. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

They do, but there is a more theoretical difference between a 3MB photo and a 1MB photo as desktop background. The number of icons may be relevant and an animated background by a third party application may slow down your mac, too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
Larger picture files do occupy more resources.
However if you consider the RAM size of current computer, 2MB is somewhat marginal difference.